# JDBC in makefile

Tags: java, database, jdbc

I'm trying to write a makefile for a java project as below. I have a database connected (installed and tested working when I compile with another IDE instead of javac).  I am not sure how to write the driver into makefile. For the following makefile, after typing make, I got message: package com.mysql.jdbc does not exist. But I have mysql-connector-java-5.1.16-bin.jar in the same folder as my makefile.

```
JFLAGS = -g
JC = javac\

.SUFFIXES: .java .class
.java.class:
    $(JC) $(JFLAGS) $*.java

JavaLibraries = \
      mysql-connector-java-5.1.16-bin.jar 

CLASSES = \
    DBMain.java\
    Update.java\
    server.java\
    Client.java

default: classes

classes: $(CLASSES:.java=.class)

clean:
    $(RM) *.class
```

Thanks for any input.

Comment: Why are you creating a makefile for Java projects? Use ANT or even better MAVEN!

Comment: You really need to use ANT or another Java based make equivalent. If you are in a project that has multiple languages then you can always call the ANT build from your MAKEFILE. Other than that look at the syntax for javac and make sure you are including the libraries in the classpath - In your case $(JC) $(JFLAGS) -classpath$(JavaLibraries)

Answer (score 2):

I cannot emphasize enough that Java and make doesn't fit well together. It's likely you will run into serious problems by building a Java project with make.

However, if you really want to use make, despite all warnings, then you have to adjust the classpath settings for the Java compiler:

```
JFLAGS = -g
JC = javac
CLASSPATH=mysql-connector-java-5.1.16-bin.jar:.

.SUFFIXES: .java .class
.java.class: 
      $(JC) $(JFLAGS) -cp $(CLASSPATH) $*.java

...
```

So the `CLASSPATH` consists of all used JARs and the package root directory of your *.java files (I assumed that is the current directory), separated by a colon on Unix/Linux systems or semicolon on Windows. Then in the `.java.class` rule you have to call the Java compiler with the `-cp` flag to pass the classpath.

Comment: +1 Amen! While this works, it rapidly becomes unwieldy for packages etc.

Answer (score 1):

This [*Database Schema Definition Language*](http://dbsdl.sourceforge.net/) project contains an exemplary [`build.xml`](http://dbsdl.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/dbsdl/trunk/build.xml?revision=15&view=markup) that shows how to initialize and test a database via JDBC. Note that `ant` targets are perfectly fine as make commands.

Addendum:

> I need is write a `makefile` for others to use.

This other [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6222211/jdbc-in-makefile/6227097#6227097) shows a good example of invoking `javac` directly from a `makefile`. It shows how to include the `classpath`, which may solve your immediate problem; but the approach rapidly becomes unwieldy for more elaborate builds, such as those including packages. This can be somewhat mitigated by using the [`subst`](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Text-Functions) function:

```
PKG = com.name.util
PKG_PATH = $(subst .,/,$(PKG))
```

A far simpler scheme is to write a minimal `ant` target, such as `<target name="compile"…>`, as shown [here](https://sites.google.com/site/drjohnbmatthews/manifesto); then the corresponding `make` command is simple:

```
.SUFFIXES: .java .class
.java .class: 
      ant compile
```

Certainly, the `makefile` now depends on `ant`, but `ant` is fairly [ubiquitous](http://ant.apache.org/).

Comment: Thanks a lot for suggesting an alternative, however, I had an alternative as mentioned in the question, but what I need is to write a makefile for others to use, so I still need to find how to do it in makefile, and it seems not so easily found online. Thanks in advance if you could show me how to write it in makefile :).